# Autostart Manycam with specific Images via configfile or parameter

Tags: windows, webcam

At the moment I try to figure out if it is possible to start ManyCam automaticaly showing a picture i configure via a configuration file or via command line parameters.

I am afraid that this might be not possible so i also search for similary software as manycam, which enables this options. Additionally the software must run on windows.